# Summation of terms of an exponential progression.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, exponentiation

I was recently considering a progression where each term in the sequence is the previous term raised to a common exponent.

To elucidate:

$$S_{E.P}(a,m)=a,a^m,{(a^m)}^m,({(a^m)}^m)^m \cdot \cdot \cdot $$
$$=>S_{E.P}(a,m)=a^{m^0},a^{m^1},a^{m^2},a^{m^3} \cdot \cdot \cdot $$

Discernably, the $n^{th}$ term in the sequence is $a^{m^{n-1}}$.

While arriving at a general formula for the product of terms of this sequences  is very easy, I'm having difficulty arriving at a generalized formula for the sum of terms of a particular sequence. Is there any concrete way for me to attempt this in a clever manner? Does a generalized formula even exist for such a sequence?

Comment: It might help to add an example, such as $S({1\over2},2)={1\over2},{1\over4},{1\over16},{1\over256},\ldots,$ to emphasize that you are not simply looking at a geometric progression.

Comment: Is $m$ an integer ?

Comment: This should be called a doubly exponential progression, shouldn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no closed formula. Evaluation by the Euler-Maclaurin formula is also out of reach.

Anyway, the exponents are increasing exponentially so that in many cases the last term is largely dominant ($|a|>1$ and the series diverges) or quickly neglectible ($|a|<1$).